# Turning a linear problem (FDA) into quadratic optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to transform this problem into a quadratic optimization problem with a quadratic constraint:
$$g = x'Ax / x'Bx$$

with constraint
$$ x'Bx = 1$$

I know that a quadratic optimization problem can have such  a form:

[Quadratic optimization problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtEsb.png)

I am stuck at how to apply this to my original formula.
How can I transform my function into this quadratic form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimization of $$\frac{x^tAx}{x^tBx}$$ subject to $$x^tBx = 1$$ is the same as minimization of $$x^tAx$$ subject to $$x^tBx = 1$$The latter problem is a QCQP (Quadratically Constrained Quadratic program). This particular QCQP is necessarily non-convex due to the nonlinear equality constraint.